# lambda calling inquiry (python)

Tags: python, lambda

I finally understood lambdas! or so I thought

why does this not work:

**Example 1:**

```
for x in range(18, 101):
    print("Man's age: ", x, "Women's age: ", lambda x:x//2+9(x))
```

yet this does:

**Example 2:**

```
for x in range(18, 101):
    print("Man's age: ", x, "Women's age: ", (lambda x:x//2+9)(x))
```

does this mean putting a lambda on a parenthesis is the equivalent of calling it? and putting another open/close parenthesis next to it means it is it's arguments?

Comment: why do you think first would work?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I didn't know. I just got the lambda concept down man. but yeah I get it now. the parenthesis calls it. and the parenthesis next to it will be treated as it's arguments

Comment: No, the first paranthesis tells exactly where the lambda starts and ends, the `(x)` calls it and `x` is the parameter. In the first case without parameter, how would python know you didn't mean to call `9` as a function? `9(x)` ?

Comment: ok gotcha.  so that's why. ok I got it now.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you are printing a `lambda` function definition

if the same if you assign it to a variable and try to print it.

```
v  = lambda x:x//2+9(x)
print v
>>function <lambda> at 0x10c32aaa0
```

If you want to execute it, you need to do `v(x)`

But, you will get an error because `9(x)` statement, is trying to call a function using an int.

The proper way to use it

```
v  = lambda x:x//2+9
print v(2)
>>10
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda defines the function but doesn't actually call it. It's the difference of just "f" and "f(x)". A clearer solution would look like:

```
func = lambda x: x//2+9

for x in range(18, 101):
    print("Man's age: ", x, "Women's age: ", func(x))
```

Comment: but doing so would defeat the use of lambda as an **"anonymous"** function yeah? it would make a clearer solution and personally I prefer your suggestion. I was just wondering why it didn't work and why the other one did